# Data from JSON to php?

Tags: php, json

I need help with fetching only attraction data,
i have this php script on my website:

```
    <?php $json_string = 'http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php'; $jsondata file_get_content($json_string); $json_o=json_decode(utf8_encode($data)); $attractie = $json_o['Id']['Type']; echo $attractie ?>
```

and this json data:

http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php

I need to convert only a Id and type, ff somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

To access the data you're looking for, you'll need to do something like this:

```
foreach ($json_o['AttractionInfo'] as $a) {
    echo $a['Id']; //or whatever you're planning to do with this data
    ech0 $a['Type'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I gonna try it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json_data = file_get_contents('http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php');
$data = json_decode($json_data);
$array = [];
foreach($data->AttractionInfo as $item) {
    $array['id'][] = $item->Id;
    $array['type'][] = $item->Type;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

$url = "http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php";

$content = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($content,TRUE);

$array = $data['AttractionInfo'];

foreach($array as $r)
{
  echo "ID->".$r['Id'];

echo '
';

echo "Type->".$r['Type'];

echo '
';

}

Comment: i get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: <?php
$url = "http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php"; 
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($content,TRUE);
$array = $data['AttractionInfo'];
foreach($array as $r)
{
  echo "ID->".$r['Id'];
  echo '<br>';
  echo "Type->".$r['Type'];
  echo '<br>';
}
?>

Comment: i get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: use     is_array($array){  foreach(){   } }

Comment: <?php
$url = "http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php"; 
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($content,TRUE);
$array = $data['AttractionInfo'];
if(is_array($array)){
foreach($array as $r)
{
  echo "ID->".$r['Id'];
  echo '<br>';
  echo "Type->".$r['Type'];
  echo '<br>';
}
}
?>

Comment: $url = "http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php";
 
$content = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($content,TRUE);

$array = $data['AttractionInfo'];

   if(is_array($array))
  {

   foreach($array as $r)
   {
     echo $r['Id'];

     echo $r['Type'];
   }

}

Answer (score 0):

$url = "http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php";

$content = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($content,TRUE);

$array = $data['AttractionInfo'];

if(is_array($array))
  {

foreach($array as $r)
   {
     echo $r['Id'];

```
 echo $r['Type'];
```

}

}